# collapse all code blocks in visual studio not working properly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As some of you might know in Visual Studio you can hit Ctrl+M+O to minimise all blocks of code, this works fine for user defined methods like

```
public Foo()
{
    string Bar= "Hello World";
}
```

and multiline comments but how come when you define a region like this

```
#region Variables
string Foo="Bar"
string Bar="Foo"
#endregion
```

it does the opposite and expands it even if it was already minimised? is there something i need to enable in the settings?

Comment: That it expands the region is certainly a bug.  But yes, an option can fix your problem.  Use Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > tick "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions".

Comment: thanks @HansPassant its been bugging me for ages that it would expand the regions because i have a really large class with lots of sql stings that i have in a region but when i collapse things they would expand which made quick navigation less quick